# Add Users with Javascript after Client PeoplePicker is loaded

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin, people-picker

the following MSDN article describes how to use the Client PeoplePicker with Javascript:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/jj713593(v=office.15).aspx

I have an SharePoint hosted app (2013) and I am saving the user Keys to a hidden list in my app.

But what is the most elegant way to initialize the people picker with the previous saved users?

Btw: I am assuming that I already have a string Array with the correct user ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answere for my own question.

I posted the answere already in another Question:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/92360/24191

The solution I posted did it for me.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian,
This comes at a great time! :)

Answer (score 1):

SPServices by our very own Uncle Marc (Anderson) has a jQuery plugin that does exactly this. His function resolves display names, so you might want to get them out, or resolve the keys to user display names manually by interrogating the user info list.

[Here are the docs for that function.](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPFindPeoplePicker)

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion. Seems like this is for SharePoint 2007 / 2010.

I found a easy solution in 2013. There is a Function in the API which is doing what I want. I post this as an answere.