# How to get People Picker ID using Javascript

Tags: 2013, javascript, sharepoint-addin, jquery, people-picker

Is there any way to get the People Picker value using Jquery/JavaScript?

Currently we use title tag to get the id of our input fields values but people picker has only one generic title field even if you have 2 or more people picker field. What we have now is get the generated ID of People Picker in our script

**e.g:**

```
var assignedUserVal = $('#ctl00_ctl41_g_2e64d0f7_f440_4b7c_9c50_383fe595b704_ff51_ctl00_ctl00_UserField_upLevelDiv').text();
```

Yesterday we have encounter this issue that when our master page has been change, the SharePoint Field ID is also change
from **ctl00_ctl41_g** to **ctl00_ctl42_g** that why we just change the id's to fix the issue.

Comment: is assignedUser a column of a list?

Answer (score 2):

If this is in some SharePoint form you could use the `SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict`  object to get the values. The `WPQ2FormCtx` object have the ID of all your PeoplePickers in the form. If you take a look under `WPQ2FormCtx.ListSchema.YourFieldInternalName.TopLevelElementId`. Then you could use it like this:

```
SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[  WPQ2FormCtx.ListSchema.YourFieldInternalName.TopLevelElementId  ].GetAllUserInfo()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a know property of .NET controls

You can use like this

```
document.getElementById('<%= "PeopleEditorID".ClientID %>').click()
```

or use  you can use ClientIDMode property for you element. If you set it into Static then the ClientID value will be set to the value of the ID property:

```
<SharePoint:PeopleEditor ID="PeopleEditorID" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Now use the ClientID in your JavaScript code to get the ID (PeopleEditorID)

Source: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119018/javascript-getelementbyid-for-asp-net-control-returns-null)

Comment: also add a little information. script must be inside page. script link will not work

Answer (score 0):

(other answer) server-side code will only be of help if you can change the New/Edit-Forms and add .Net code

If you want to monkey patch after the form is displayed,
you can get an DOM object array of all PeoplePickers with:

```
var pPickers=document.querySelectorAll('.sp-peoplepicker-topLevel');
```

*no jQuery required*
First element in the array is the first PeoplePicker on the screen

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in jquery.

```
var User;

var inputuserfield = $("div[title='People Picker']"); 

var UserControlSpan = $("span[title='UserField']").find(inputuserfield);

 if (UserControlSpan != null && UserControlSpan.text() != null && UserControlSpan.text().trim().length > 1 ) {
     User =  UserControlSpan.text().trim();
  }
```

I will suggest you to add a SPAN around your people control. Reason :if you  have multiple people controls then you will get wrong result as all people control will have same title. Give different ID to each SPAN.

If you have only 1 people picker field on the page use the below code:

```
var User;

var inputuserfield = $("div[title='People Picker']"); 

 if (inputuserfield != null && inputuserfield.text() != null && inputuserfield.text().trim().length > 1 ) {
     User =  inputuserfield.text().trim();
  }
```

Mark this as answer if works for you, someone might be looking for same

Answer (score 0):

If the field id is dynamic you can use startswith operator to get value from that field. like if you are taking 'title' then take it as 
var value = $('input[title^="title"]').val(); here atleast field name should start with title then if the dynamic value changes still you can access the value of title field.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
var RequestedForpeoplePicker = this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.RequestedFor_TopSpan;
    var RequestedForu = RequestedForpeoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
```

and my peoplepicker

```
<div>
                <SharePoint:ClientPeoplePicker Required="true" ValidationEnabled="true" ID="RequestedFor" UseLocalSuggestionCache="true" PrincipalAccountType="User" runat="server" VisibleSuggestions="3" Rows="1" AllowMultipleEntities="false" CssClass="ms-long ms-spellcheck-true user-block" ErrorMessage="" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoFillEnabled="True"/>                
            </div>
```

Check the id and clientIdMode before using it

Answer (score 0):

You should use `SPClientPeoplePicker` - default JS object for SP2013.

More info see there:
[Get the ID and Name from multiple Client side People pickers to store in a list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/87176/get-the-id-and-name-from-multiple-client-side-people-pickers-to-store-in-a-list)

Using `SPClientPeoplePicker` you can read members, write member, use groups and filters

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the picker id for SharePoint Client People Picker change event. I have got the same using `OnUserResolvedClientScript` as below. Here to get the picker div I have followed the approach of getting it via the people picker text box `id` and the `title name` which you can get the by inspecting the element. put the below code in  `$(document).ready` function. Happy Coding

---

```
 SP.SOD.executeFunc('clientpeoplepicker.js', 'SPClientPeoplePicker', function() {
  var pickerDiv = $("[id^='Employee_x0020_Name'][title='Employee Name']");
  var picker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[pickerDiv[0].id];
  picker.OnUserResolvedClientScript = function(peoplePickerId, 
 selectedUsersInfo) {
  //It will get the desired display name of the people from picker div, 
   //similarly any other property can be accessed via selectedUsersInfo
    var empname = selectedUsersInfo[0].DisplayText;
    console.log(empname);
  }
});
```